# ASP.NET nothing changes when I edit the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, web

I have this ASP.NET application, and suddenly it doesn't show the changes, if I edit a css file for example, even if I rebuild it and run it like that. I tried with an older version of the app too but it does the same. Is it from some Visual Studio setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with VS2015/2017, consider deleting the ".vs" folder that could be found at the root of your application i.e. the same folder where your solution file is present. If the folder isn't there you may have to unhide it through folder options.

The folder will get created again next time you build/run your application.

Answer (score 1):

Try to clear the browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have tried "ctrl + f5" which will hard refresh (Cache will restore) your crome and make sure everything has been saved inside vs, Also make sure you are passing through the .css file properly.

Comment: Ctrl+R also will do it

Comment: @AntDC: That depends on the browser. CTRL + R behaves the same way as F5 in some browser, so it will not delete the page's cache.